# Need advice. How to remove restrictions in the number of words (spans)?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm creating a theme for sale on themeforest and there's a little problem with the text that has the animation. The thing is that all the headlines in my theme have animation. In this animation, each word is allocated in a separate span and each subsequent span appears 0.05 seconds later than the previous one. And it turns out that users get can able to edit these spans (change the text), but can not able to add. And imagine if the user needed to write in the heading 15 words, and spans only 10. Is it possible to do something so that a person can add an unlimited number of words. That is to each new written them word are automatically allocated in a separate span and set certain settings. And this span will appeared at 0.05 later than the previous? And so with every word?

I'm new to wordpress. I hope you understand me.

I made a demonstration. Please look at the headlines to understand what kind of animation I mean: http://bogdans-ultra-awesome-project-10773e.webflow.io

Answer (score 0):

You can take the string from a field in Wordpress admin area, and then add the span tag for each one regardless of how long the text is.

Comment: I a little bit don't understand. Could you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: The concept is simple: you save the title as string using the let’s say the title box in Wordpress, in your theme once you get the title, using php you can use a “while” going through the string adding the span tag for each one.

Comment: $title = get_title();
$letter = str_split($str);// now your string is an array

Comment: Yes, but what about animation? The user will be able to add spans, but these spans will be deprived of animation

Comment: The idea of all that is the user doesn't have to be worried about the span. The main idea is the user just add the text and you through PHP create the spans necessaries to do the animation.